# Nested accordions - how do you keep the parent open when clicking on the child

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-accordion

We're trying to build out a data-driven list using nested accordions. In our first prototype, it worked well, but we were hard-coding the implementation and had clearly distinct accordions.

Now as we move to make that load dynamically, it looks like the structure is there, but we no longer have distinct accordions, so they don't operate independently. Is there something we can add to the custom binding that will make this work? Or some other property we can set to keep the child accordions separate.

This example only nests 2 levels deep, but we'll ultimately need to support 4.

Here's the current prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/blunde/agjFn/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle which I believe fixes the issue you were having.

http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/gbhfT/6/

view

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items, accordion: {}">
    <h3>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: id"></a>
    </h3>
    <div>    
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <div data-bind="foreach: items, accordion: {}">
            <h3>
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: id"></a>
            </h3>
            <div data-bind="text: name">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <button data-bind="click: add">Add Sub Item</button>
    </div> 
</div>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add Item</button>
<hr/>
```

Javascript

```
ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).accordion(options);
        }, 0);

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).accordion("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion(options);
    }
}

function Item(id, name, subItems) {
    var self = this;

    //properties
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.items = ko.observableArray(subItems);

    //actions
    this.add = function() {
        self.items.push(new Item(4, "bar"));
    };
}

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item(1, "one", 
            [
             new Item(11, "one-one"), 
             new Item(12, "one-two")
            ]),
        new Item(2, "two", []), 
        new Item(3, "three", []) 
    ]),

    add: function() {
        viewModel.items.push(new Item(4, "foo"));
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

​

You should be able to make this work n-levels deep by changing the foreach into a template.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

I hope this helps!

Jason